# android unique id for each device like serial number

Tags: android, mysql, uniqueidentifier

I have a samsung j5. I am using the Serial Number that can be found in

> Settings > About Device > Status > Serial Number.

It has a value of `RF8H933KWLF` which I assume to be unique. Now I register this value to my database and when I run my app I send a request to my database and check if the device I use is registered in my database. The way I get the Serial Number of device is:

```
String serialNumber = "";
try {
  Class <? > c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
  Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class, String.class);
  serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "sys.serialnumber", "Error");
  if (serialNumber.equals("Error")) {
    serialNumber = (String) get.invoke(c, "ril.serialnumber", "Error");
  }

} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For my device I can get a correct value.

My question is why when I use a different device I cant get the value that I see in the `Serial Number`.

1. I tried on device and it returns `Error`.
2. What could be an alternative ID I can use that is unique to a device (does not change even if device is restored or rooted).
3. I need the ID to be visible so before hand I can register it to my database to allow access to app's login.

Answer (score 0):

refer this you can find many other ways  [Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id?rq=1)

```
  import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

 private String android_id = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
                                                    Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Comment: i tried this id but as documentation says it will change when device is restored or rooted. and i dont want that one. also i have no way to get this ID so that i  can register it unlike serial number where i can just go to `Settings > About Device > Status > Serial Number.` then store that value to database

Comment: refer that question , there are many other ways you can get the device id, check all answers once, atleast one of it should work

Comment: I have only one question where can i see that value in device?I need to see it before hand so I can register it to my database.

Comment: in that question see  +Seva Alekseyev   answer , you can see that going to  wifi->advanced MAC address

Comment: i also tried this one problem is my MAC output is `02:00:00:00:00:00` which is not the MAC Address it the phone also i read somewhere that this will always be the output

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **combination** of there **phone number** and **IMEI** number to get the **unique Id**.
You can ask phone number to user and also device can show IMEI numbers.
To get IMEI number and phone number programmatically do something like this.

```
TelephonyManager teleMan = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
// get IMEI number 
String imei = teleMan.getDeviceId();
//get The Phone Number
String phone = teleMan.getLine1Number();
```

Hope this solves it.
Note :- I haven't tried this yet.